# eclipselink connection pooling

Tags: jpa, jdbc, eclipselink, connection-pooling

If connection pooling is not defined in the persistence.xml for eclipse link, what is the default behavior?

Will it open and close a JDBC connection for every transaction? Will it create a connection pool with some defaults?

Comment: Which transaction-type have you specified in your persistence.xml?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default connection pooling for EclipseLink when not using a data source is a pool of min/max 32 connections, with an initial of 1 connections.  So each transaction will use a pooled connection, and not connect/disconnect.

Comment: Are you saying the eclipselink supports connection pooling even if there is no reference for pooling in the persistence.xml file?

Comment: Yes, that is the default (pool of 32 connections)

Comment: And here are the configuration properties: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm

Comment: I don't understand this. I have not configured anything. If I start a lot of transactions in a very short amount of time, netstation shows me the same lot of TCP connections in TIME_WAIT state. Shouldn't it, If I assume you are right, be limited to a total of 32 connections here??

Comment: Have you any reference of this?

Comment: Also, partially relevant, is it known the meaning of the current default? I mean, if "min" is 32, how can be "initial" 1 (that is, under the min). Maybe useful to be integrated, if known.

Answer (score 7):

If you use an application server (Java EE) and container managed persistence, then you need to set up the connection pooling in the administration console of the application server, and don't need to set the pooling properties in the persistence.xml, e.g.:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc_my_DataSource</jta-data-source>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
  <properties/>
</persistence-unit>
```

If you use EclipseLink without application server (Java SE), using application managed persistence, then if you don't configure pooling, [Internal Connection Pooling](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Data_Access_%28ELUG%29#Internal_Connection_Pools) will be used, e.g.:

```
<persistence-unit name="DemoPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: When you mean App server do you mean EE or SE? So when no connection pooling is defined its a connection for every tx? What about bean managed persistence using Spring/Tomcat?

Comment: Eclipselink still uses connection pools, it is just that it maintains the pool instead of using a datasource.  Eclipselink internal pools are somewhat described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_an_Internal_Connection_Pool_(ELUG) and jpa persistence properties to use are posted here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Features/JPA#EntityManagerFactory_Properties

Answer (score 2):

```
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1"/>
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="64"/>
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="64"/>
```

Comment: 1/32/32 as James said appears correct (see source code I referenced in my answer in this thread.)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to provide the code source for James' answer above: You can see that a default connection pool is created in the constructors of [ServerSession](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/src/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/server/ServerSession.java), using the init/min/max defaults defined in [ConnectionPool](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/src/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/server/ConnectionPool.java), and optionally overridden/adjusted by the developer via properties in [EntityManagerSetupImpl](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/EntityManagerSetupImpl.java#L1531).

Comment: The links are not available anymore. It's a pity since this was the only answer with references.