# EclipseLink connections deadlock

Tags: java, eclipselink, deadlock

Single threaded standalone java app entering a deadlock? Yes, with EclipseLink this is very easy. So after a week of debugging a very complex multi threaded app, I managed to narrow down the problem to this:

If you have only 1 thread in application, you'd assume that you need a DB connection pool of size 1 and that everything should work. Well, not in this case:

```
public void singleThreadedMethod() {
    User u;

    --start JPA transaction / create EM (1)--
    u = em.find(User.class, userId);
    -- end  JPA transaction / close EM --

    --start JPA transaction / create EM (2)--
    u.getCompany(); // lazy assoc (3)
    -- end  JPA transaction / close EM--
}
```

EclipseLink will take 1 connection for (1), then return it to the pool. Then take another connection for (2), then try to take another connection for (3), although it looks like the code is inside a single transaction. Trick is that `u` is not managed in this transaction (2), but still "manages" to get to the DB to get its lazy association. If the DB pool size is 1, this creates a deadlock, since (2) is holding the only connection that (3) (inside (2)) is waiting on. Note that this is NOT a deadlock in DB, but in connection pool in Java.

This creates a debugging nightmare when you have pool of 20 connections and less than 20 threads and you wonder where that deadlock comes from!

I guess it's a long shot, but - is there any way to stop EclipseLink from doing what it does? I.e. to stop it from fetching lazy associations when not inside persistence context? Or to use thread's existing persistence context if it's there.

Comment: I didn't test it personally but perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119095/eclipselink-connection-pooling can help. If I understood correctly, if you use internal connection pool they don't do this reconnection. Just a guess.