# Configure Connection Pool with EclipseLink

Tags: tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, connection-pooling

I am currently working in a project with:

```
jsf 2.1.2, eclipseLink 2.4.1, sql server 2008 windows authentication and Apache tomcat 7.0
```

I already set up the connection and jndi and everything works fine.

There is another requierement, I have to configure a connection pool because i will have only one connection (because of the win authentication), Do you know the best way to configure a connection pooling with JPA? is it posible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one web application on your tomcat you can use the internal [Eclipselink connection pool](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm). (You might also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119095/eclipselink-connection-pooling))

But if you have several applications or you need a different connection pool you should first disable the Eclipselink internal pool and setup a datasource in your tomcat and use [tomcat connection pool](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) (or any other solution). Finally, you should modify your persistence.xml to point to this datasource.

Comment: Eclipselink is a very solid product and I would recommend its connection pool. James Sutherland the Oracle lead for the project is very responsive on SO and the Eclipselink mailing list. Since you are already using it, it will help min. your projects external dependencies.